# Exiting an ongoing Node.js server in linux

Tags: linux, node.js

When I run my node server `node server.js` through SSH, the server starts and operates properly, however, I am left at the command prompt on a blank line, and no matter what I try to do, I can't "escape" out of that back to `root /]#`.  Is it necessary for me to terminate the session completely and rerun a new SSH session to be able to operate on the prompt again?

I'm sure this is a completely basic problem with a completely basic solution, I just can't for the life of me seem to "escape" out of this back to the command line.  It would seem unlikely that it would be necessary to completely exit out of PuTTy and start a new session just to terminate it..

Comment: Have you tried pressing Ctrl + C, that usually exits most servers I start via the CLI.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  I had tried Ctrl+X, Ctrl+Q, ESC, END, DELETE, etc.. glad that is sorted out.

Comment: @Derrick Tucker you might want to try `Ctrl + D` when `Ctrl + C` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going to post as an answer, have you tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or as Gabi mentioned, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, that usually exits most servers I start via the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/) (quick reference [here](http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference)) to simultaneously work with multiple terminal interfaces within existing PuTTy session.